# Jersey + OWL API 3

Tags: java, owl-api

Good morning people.

I am trying to load an ontology from a Restfull service using Jersey. However, my application throws exception in the following line:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager = ();
```

I thank the help of all.

**Error log:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**My web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SemanticMDX</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**My Service:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/semantichelper")
public class WS_SemanticMDX {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String convertCtoF() {
        AssistenteSemantico moduloSemantico = new AssistenteSemantico();
        moduloSemantico.loadOWLOntology();

    return "";
    }
}
```

Method to load ontology:

```
public class AssistenteSemantico {
public static final IRI iri = IRI.create(
        "myIRI/NovaOntologiaDeFeriados.owl");

public OWLOntology loadOwlOntology(){
    OWLOntology owlOntologyRedirect = null;
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 

    manager.addIRIMapper(new SimpleIRIMapper(
            iri,
            IRI.create(new File(myPath/OntologiaDeFeriados-v4.owl"))));
    try {
        owlOntologyRedirect = manager.loadOntology(iri);
    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return owlOntologyRedirect;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SemanticMDX</groupId>
<artifactId>SemanticMDX</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

error after adding the jar OWL API both in WEB-INF / lib as in diterório lib tomcat:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
```

1) No implementation for java.util.Set was bound.
  while locating java.util.Set
    for parameter 0 at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyStorers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
  at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.setOntologyStorers(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
  at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLAPIImplModule.configure(OWLAPIImplModule.java:61)

2) An exception was caught and reported. Message: org.semanticweb.owlapi.oboformat.OBOFormatOWLAPIParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.inject.Provider
  at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)

2 errors
    com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:89)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.instatiateOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:97)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:58)
    AssistenteSemantico.carregarOwlOntology(AssistenteSemantico.java:35)
    AssistenteSemantico.inferirDiasParteDeIntervaloPorNomeindividuo(AssistenteSemantico.java:112)
    WS_SemanticMDX.convertCtoF(WS_SemanticMDX.java:17)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.semanticweb.owlapi.oboformat.OBOFormatOWLAPIParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.inject.Provider
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.loadFactories(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:109)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.configure(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:59)
    com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
    com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:89)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.instatiateOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:97)
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:58)
    AssistenteSemantico.carregarOwlOntology(AssistenteSemantico.java:35)
    AssistenteSemantico.inferirDiasParteDeIntervaloPorNomeindividuo(AssistenteSemantico.java:112)
    WS_SemanticMDX.convertCtoF(WS_SemanticMDX.java:17)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Answer (score 0):

Your pom file looks correct, but the error seems to suggest the OWLAPI jars are not being included correctly in your web application. Check the content of `WEB-INF/lib`, the `owlapi-distribution` jar should be there.

Edit: The new error cannot happen with OWLAPI 3 - it refers to code that's only available in OWLAPI 4. I believe you now have multiple versions in your classpath.

Comment: Add the jar of OWL API both in WEB-INF / lib as in diterório lib tomcat. I edited the post and added the new error that arose.

Comment: Looks like multiple versions now.

Comment: thank you Ignazio. updated versions of OWL API and Pellet and everything worked perfectly.